# Could ions inside lungs produce hydroxyl?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry

I am not proficient in either biology or chemistry. However, I have a question which I can't find answer to. It seems to belong somewhere between chemistry and biology. I apologize for any errors and inconsistencies in this post.

There is a page (https://allergytech.com/sharp_plasmacluster_ion.htm) which describes a process. During this process, positive and negative ions are released to the air. They are called clusters.

> The clusters seek out and surround harmful airborne substances such as
>   fungi, viruses, microbes, bacteria, plant and mold spores, dust mite
>   debris, etc. At this point, a chemical reaction occurs, and the
>   collision of hydrogen with oxygen ions creates groups of highly
>   reactive OH radicals, called hydroxyl - Nature’s form of a Detergent.

[image]

> A hydroxyl radical is very unstable. To stabilize itself, it robs the
>   hydrogen from any harmful airborne particles it encounters. Doing so,
>   the hydroxyl radical damages the harmful micro organisms and
>   deactivates them.

[image]

Below is my question.

Suppose that a human breaths in those clusters as soon as they are released to the air. Is there a possibility that inside lungs, they will encounter something that will trigger similar reaction, and in effect hydroxyl will be created, too?

Comment: I’m sorry but questions on SE Biology should be comprehensible in themselves, without the requirement to go to some third party website which may be booby-trapped or disappear tomorrow. You need to post the images at the very least.  From what you write your understanding of chemistry seems deficient. You need to sort that out too, because at the moment what you write makes no chemical sense.

Comment: Thank you. I’ve looked at the page. It seems to be an ad for snake oil.

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's an ad. The technology is described in other places like [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5011831/) and [here](https://vdocuments.site/evaluation-of-the-nano-confined-catalytic-oxidation-technology-for-air-purification.html). But I can't find explanation what happens to the lungs when you inhale those ions, whether they could break lung cells like they break airborne particles.